# need a hint about in functional analysis (how prove $\Vert f\Vert_{C([0,1])} ≤ c\Vert g\Vert_{C(J)}?$)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Please suggest a hint to me not a whole solution.

> **Problem**
>   Let $J ⊂ [0,1]$ be closed and consider a closed subspace $E$ of $C([0,1]).$ Assume that for all
>   $g \in C(J)$ there exists $f \in E$ such that
>   $$ f(t) = g(t)\;\;\; \forall t \in J. $$
>   Show that one can find a constant $c$ independent of $g$ such that the following statement holds:
>   $\forall g \in C(J)$ there exists $f \in E$ such that $f(t) = g(t)$ and $\Vert f\Vert_{C([0,1])} ≤ c\Vert g\Vert_{C(J)}.$

Comment: I am sorry I edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a bounded linear map $T: E \to C(J)$, by $f \mapsto f|_E$.

Define a quotient Banach space $X:=E/\ker T$, whose norm is defined by $$\|f+\ker T\|:=\inf\{ \|f-h\|:h\in \ker T\}$$

Then let $S:X \to C(J)$ be the quotient map induced from $T$, i.e., $S(f+\ker T) = Tf$. This map is bounded and injective by construction. It is also surjective by the condition given in the problem.

By the bounded inverse theorem, $S^{-1}$ is actually bounded, therefore there exists $C>0$ such that $$\inf\{\|f-h\|:h\in \ker T\} \leq C \|Tf\|_{C(J)} $$ Is this a good enough hint?

Comment: Thanks a lot. After the last inequality, can we say since, $T$ is injective so 
$\inf\{\|f-h\|:h\in \ker T\} =\|f\|_{C([0,1])},$
and, since $T$ is surjective so
$\|Tf\|_{C(J)}=\|g\|_{C(J)}$??

Comment: @HamedBaghalGhaffari No that is not correct. $T$ is definitely **not** injective in general. To finish the proof, take any $g \in C(J)$. We know that $g=f|_E=Tf$ for some $f \in E$. Then using the fact that $$\inf_{h \in \ker T} \|f-h\| \leq C\|Tf\|_{C(J)}=C\|g\|_{C(J)}$$ we find that there exists some $h \in \ker T$ such that $\|f-h\| \leq 2C\|g\|_{C(J)}$. Then the function $\tilde f:=f-h$ satisfies the desired claim, since $h|_E=Th=0$.